# Autosave web browser content at perticular time intervals

Tags: c#

I am making a web browser which will autosave it's content at a time intervals and save as text file at specified location in local drive with file name 001,002,003.... etc. I am doing making this browser for collecting the stock price at specific intervals. i am doing this in visual c#.if any one know how i can do this in c#, please replay me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WebClient.DownloadFile` method to save a URL to disk.